# convert from OEM 866 charset (cyrillic) to UTF?

Tags: character-encoding

I have a large csv text file exported from a Russian database. The character set is OEM 866 which is unreadable to most of the applications I will be using to work with the file. Is there a way to convert it to UTF-8 or ANSI?

My attempted solution:

1) Identify the character set as Cyrillic OEM 866 in Notepad++. The file is now readable in Notepad++. 
2) In Notepad++, tried convert to UTF-8, UTF8 w/o BOM, ANSI. Naturally, Notepad++ reads the converted "ANSI" or "UTF" file it just created. But no other program does.

Apologies if this is a silly question - because I really don't know much about the subject.

Comment: Just run this command: `iconv -f IBM866 -t UTF-8 < inputfile > outputfile`

Comment: @tchrist didn't work for me, but notepad++ shows everything well and converts well too.

Answer (score 1):

If Notepad++ can read a UTF-8 encoded file, especially one that it created, then other apps that support UTF-8 encoded files should be able to read the same file as well. Not all apps support a UTF-8 BOM in text files, but if you are still having problems with and without a BOM present, then you should be looking at problems with those apps before suspecting a problem with the UTF-8 file. Those apps are likely not loading the text file as UTF-8 to begin with, and if that happens then they would be interpreting the file contents incorrectly. Many apps tend to load 8bit text files assuming the OS default Ansi encoding is used, instead of UTF-8 or other encoding, so you might need to tell those apps to load the text file as UTF-8, if such an option is available (that is where BOMs come into play if there is no such option available).

Answer (score -1):

tchrist's iconv sounds like the best option if you are using Unix, but since you are using Notepad++, I think you are on Windows.

You probably don't want a manual workaround, but since nobody else posted a better one, here is a cludge that worked for me.

Open the file in Notepad++. Make sure encoding is set correctly (Click "Encoding --> Character sets --> Cyrillic --> OEM 866) I know you got that far on your own, but it's there for the benefit of others.

Select all, copy. Open regular old Notepad. Paste.

Click "File --> Save As" and before saving, make sure the Encoding option next to the save button says UTF-8. (ANSI is the default but it doesn't have Cyrillic characters)

I don't know why saving in Notepad++ didn't work, but I had the same experience you did.